# How to keep AppBar Title centered after navigating to next screen

Tags: flutter, center, title, titlebar, appbar

How do I keep the appbar title center after navigating to next screen.  When I navigate to the next screen, the back arrow Button "<" comes up which shifts the title to the right.  How can I keep the title centered?  I tried centerTitle = True but didn't work

```
appBar: AppBar(
  centerTitle: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
  title: Center(
    child: Text(
      kAppBarTitle,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `centerTitle: true`, do not use `Center` widget inside your `title` parameter.

```
appBar: AppBar(
  centerTitle: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
  title: Text(
      kAppBarTitle,
   ),
),
```

That's all you need to fix it.